# Adding Properties in a forEach Loop in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

lets say each post in my posts array has two properties name and number. so its something like

```
var posts = [{name:"hey", number: 1}, {name:"foo", number:"2"}]
```

Javascript allows me to change these properties in foreach loop like this:

```
posts.forEach(function(post){
    post.name = "bar"
});
```

and my array becomes:

```
var posts = [{name:"bar", number: 1}, {name:"bar", number:"2"}]
```

but it doesnt allow me add a new property like:

```
posts.forEach(function(post){
    post.adress = "bar"
});
```

my object stays the same. Is there a way to add properties in a foreach loop in javascipt

edit:

this is happening using mongoose inside a callback..

```
  Post.pagination(options, function(err, posts) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    posts.forEach(function(post){
      post.votetype = 1;
    });
    console.log(posts);
    res.send({ posts : posts  })
  })
```

after this votetype property is not added

Comment: Are you sure? I get the result you desire: http://jsfiddle.net/dAHJz/ . Look in the console and expand the array (and its objects) and you'll see the `address` property was added to each

Comment: Is this in the browser or on the server side using Node.js with Mongoose (or something similar)?

Comment: using mongoose.. I guess I oversimplified my question

Comment: Then you will need to call `.toObject()` on the particular object, and you will then get an object which you can modify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that data returned from Mongoose is immutable.
The code below is untested but should give you a hint on how to make the data mutable and modify it.

The key point is calling `toObject()` on the Mongoose document object you wish to modify.

```
Post.pagination(options, function(err, posts) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

  var resultPosts = posts.map(function(post) {
    var tmpPost = post.toObject();

    // Add properties...
    tmpPost.votetype = 1;

    return tmpPost;
  });

  console.log(resultPosts);
  res.send({ posts : resultPosts  });
});
```

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven Glad I could help. I had the exact same problem some weeks ago. :)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about immutable objects in mongoose. This solved my problem as well! Learning every day!

Comment: Also, if you've got a doc from mongoose and won't be saving it back to the db (and want to, say, add properties), use .lean() in your query: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean