# Looping over objects to add property not working (Javascript with Mongodb)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, foreach

I want to grab a list of all the users, compare the list to a survey database to see how many votes each one of them has received, and append those vote values to the user object, and send back to the front.

I read examples on SO like this:
['TypeError: meme.find(...).forEach is not a function' in mongoose node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009832/typeerror-meme-find-foreach-is-not-a-function-in-mongoose-node-js)
and this:
[Adding Properties in a forEach Loop in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959920/adding-properties-in-a-foreach-loop-in-mongoose)

I'm trying to do the same thing.

I have simple code, but it doesn't work.

**Attempt #1**:

```
let users = await User.find({teams: {$in: req.user.team_oid}}, {_id: 1, firstname: 1, lastname: 1})

users.forEach(async(user, i) => {

    let nomineeCount = await Survey.countDocuments({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.s_oid), 'facilitators.nominee': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id) })

    user["votes"] = nomineeCount;

    if(i+1 === users.length) {res.json({users: users})}
})
```

The queries and everything is working, except the `user` does not receive the `["votes"]` property.

**Attempt #2**:

```
let users = await User.find({teams: {$in: req.user.team_oid}}, {_id: 1, firstname: 1, lastname: 1})

let nominees = users;

users.map( async (user, i) => {

let nomineeCount = await Survey.countDocuments({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.s_oid), 'facilitators.nominee': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id) })

    nominees[i].votes = nomineeCount;
        
    if(i+1 === nominees.length) {res.json({users: nominees})}
})
```

This also fails to attach the `.votes` property.

Any ideas / suggestions appreciated.

Comment: could you proivde sample data

Comment: It is very simple. `users` is: `[{_id: ObjectId, firstname: string, lastname: string }]` and for `nomineeCount` it returns `Number`

Comment: The problem here is that an async `forEach` function causes all function calls to run concurrently; you'll want to use either Promise.all or a for loop so by the time res.json() is called, they async calls are actually all finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [for await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

`for await (variable of iterable) { statement }`